# Shoutcast Radio on Android

Tags: android, shoutcast, internet-radio

I'm making an app for streaming radio content from internet ! and i spent so much time trying to find a simple source code showing how to implement a streaming content !
i found some useful links in StackOverflow but no one worked for me !!
Please i need your help !  , here is the piece of code that i made but still doesn't work ! and i don't know why !
Ps : the url of the radio station is working fine

```
package com.example.radio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener  {



    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
             mp = new MediaPlayer();
             String url="http://108.168.175.174:7120";
             mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
             mp.setDataSource(url);
             mp.prepareAsync();
             mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("ExceptionOnCreate:",e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

    }



}
```

here is the log cat :

```
05-06 10:20:07.291: E/MediaPlayer(1470): error (1, -2147483648)
05-06 10:20:07.291: E/MediaPlayer(1470): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: you see this link ?? http://android.programmerguru.com/android-mediaplayer-example-play-from-internet/

Comment: after trying the code the http link :http://108.168.175.174:7120 is not working but the mp3 link : http://android.programmerguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3 is working fine can anyone explain why the first link doesn't work !! thanks

Comment: what is the error when using link :108.168.175.174:7120?

Comment: have you find any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely due to SHOUTcast sending you to the admin interface.  If your user agent string contains `Mozilla`, then you get the admin page instead of the stream.  You can override this behavior by requesting a semicolon in your URL:

```
http://108.168.175.174:7120/;
```

That will force the server to see your user agent string as `MPEG OVERRIDE`, and it will send you the real stream.

If that doesn't fix it,  you are likely bumping up an issue where SHOUTcast servers are not HTTP compliant.  They send their status line as `ICY 200 OK` instead of `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`, which breaks many clients.